# Is the word "uphill" limited to "hill" to English speakers

Tags: spoken-english

> The children were running **uphill** towards the house.

Is the word **uphill** *(adjective and adverb)* used only in the context of **hill** or for **roads** and **any kind of surface** as well?

Can I say:

> The road is steeply **uphill.**

What's the most natural way to express this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, most roads run in two directions, so, in many contexts, it wouldn't make a lot of sense to call it an *uphill road* (since it would also be a *downhill road* when going in the other direction). Instead, we might just say something like:

> It's a hilly road.

or:

> The road has steep hills.

---

However, there may be times when describing an *uphill road* would make sense (such as when you are giving someone directions, or, say, describing a race route for runners). In this case, instead of using the verb *is*, you might use the verb *goes*:

> The road **goes** steeply uphill.

You can also use a verb that emphasizes the direction of the hill; for example:

> The road **climbs** steeply uphill.
>   The road **drops** steeply downhill.